# Datagrip: execute sql statements in oracle with a parameter

Tags: datagrip

I routinely execute this statement using `Ctrl` - `Shift` - `F10` in datagrip.
Is there any way to create a SQL or pl/SQL set of statements that contain a variable, and execute the file with DataGrip.

Datagrip's variable handling is not great - or I am missing something.

```
// somehow set $(jobName?) to a value in the file and re-use it.

update t_msg_log l
set l.job_status = 'FinishedSuccess'
where l.source_detail = $(jobName?)
  and created =
      (select max(created) from t_msg_log li where li.source_detail = l.source_detail);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called user parameters. The parameter pattern you use isn't described in DataGrip by default. You need to do this yourself.

1. Go to **Settings/Preferences | Database | User Parameters**
2. Add new parameter with this regexp: `\$\([^\)\?]+\?\)`
3. Don't forget to check 'Enable in console', 'In scripts'.
4. Enjoy!

[image]

Comment: I am accepting this answer as get's kind of close. I was hoping for something more like SQL Server (SSMS) CMD mode.

Comment: As a reference - also see the documentation for UserParameters in DataGrip docs. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/2018.2/settings-tools-database-user-parameters.html